# Strong params not permit dynamic keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

my controller is receiving this params

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"r5KaLCrb1PR//q4HZ0p30dUeK1OHE7cjtoken=",
 "servidor"=>
  {"nome"=>"USER NAME",
   "tipo"=>"1",
   "lotacao_ids"=>{"1"=>["", "86", "13"], "2"=>["", "86"], "3"=>["", "66","103","69"]},
   "contatos_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"telefone"=>"9229-8396 ", "id"=>"453"}},
   "matricula"=>"8741883",
   "cpf"=>"16450724870"},
 "action"=>"update",
 "controller"=>"servidores",
 "id"=>"238"}
```

But after passing by

```
params.require(:servidor).permit(:nome, :tipo, :matricula, :cpf, :contatos_attributes=>[:telefone,:id],:lotacao_ids=>{})
```

result in

```
{"nome"=>"USER NAME",
 "tipo"=>"1",
 "matricula"=>"8741883",
 "cpf"=>"16450724870",
 "contatos_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"telefone"=>"9229-8396 ", "id"=>"453"}},
 "lotacao_ids"=>{}}
```

how I can receive my params `lotacao_ids` as `lotacao_ids=>{1=>86, 2=>86, 3=>66}`
tnks

**Answer** with help of @phoet

```
     def servidor_params
       params.require(:servidor).permit(:nome, :tipo, :matricula, :cpf, :contatos_attributes=>[:telefone,:id]).tap do |whitelisted|        
         whitelisted["lotacao_ids"] = params[:servidor]["lotacao_ids"]
       end
     end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you want to do goes against the idea of strong parameters, because you would basically have no control over what is in that hash of `lotacao_ids`.

> Note that if you use permit in a key that points to a hash, it won't
>   allow all the hash. You also need to specify which attributes inside
>   the hash should be whitelisted.

the part of the params that you gave as an example indicate that this should actually be an array of ids instead of a hash?

in any case, if you don't care about the content of that field, you can still merge it into the hash that you get after permitting stuff in the first place. it's still just a hash...

Comment: Thanks for answer, I will update my example for best comprehension about possibility of the Hash be a Array.

And Two, how I can merge this information in my Hash? 

Thanks again.

Comment: I discovery how. Thanks for help! :D